# Cannot install Azure Dev Spaces using cloud shell in AKS

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-dev-spaces

When i run the below command in cloud shell.

```
az aks use-dev-spaces -g aksrgrp -n akscluster
```

I get the below error. Any help will be highly appreciated

```
You may be prompted for your administrator password to authorize the installation process.
/tmp/tmpy1vng2we/azds-linux-setup.sh: line 84: sudo: command not found
/tmp/tmpy1vng2we/azds-linux-setup.sh: line 112: sudo: command not found
[INFO]    Failed to install dotnet core dependencies.
[INFO]    You can manually install all required dependencies based on the following documentation:
[FATAL]   https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-core/2.1
Azure Dev Spaces CLI not installed properly. Visit 'https://aka.ms/get-azds' for Azure Dev Spaces.
```

Comment: What is the reason that makes you unmark the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error shows why the issue happens. **It cannot find the command `azds`**. Because the cloud shell does not install the command tool. You can find all the command tools installed in the cloud shell [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/features#tools).

I suggest you can install the tool which you need in the Azure VM of the azure Kubernetes, if you do not find the tool what you want.

It's a better way for you. By the way, the Cloud Shell just enables access to a browser-based command-line experience built with Azure management tasks in mind. So install the Azure CLI in the VM is a better experience.

Answer (score 2):

To add to Charles's answer: the Azure Dev Spaces CLI currently does not support running in the Cloud Shell. Its functionality is designed more for running on your local dev machine where you application's source code is.